# Практический смысл использования пространств имен в PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые коллеги. Собственно листал на досуге ман и вспомнил о пространствах имен в php, внимание вопрос: **Какой реальный практический смысл их использования?**

Я имею введу не извраты с `__autoload` и т.д., там и без них можно обойтись, а именно реальная польза какая? Лично я подозреваю, что никакой (раз вспомнил о них случайно и после изучения основ php ни разу к ним не возвращался), хотя опять-таки все мы грешны и, может, я пишу ересь...
Если же я ошибаюсь (и таки написал ересь), был бы очень признателен за кусок какого-то показательного кода, можно просто ткнуть в какой-то opensource скрипт, либу etc. Важно, чтобы в приведенном вами примере их использование было оправдано и полезно. Прошу пролить свет на сей вопрос, заранее благодарен :)

PS: На кой о них спрашивают на собеседованиях, вообще не понимаю... Вот у знакомого спросили, а он вообще не в курсе был, что это, хотя ИМХО нормальный программист...

Comment: По ходу, это что-то от крестов)) Кстати, тоже не знал, спасибо)

Comment: Почитал <a href="http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/72033/">вот сие</a>. По качеству и напористости пиара напомнило биткойн. Резюме - плюшка/наворот/бантик, практический смысл есть только для тех, кому `"use MyLib; echo MyFunc();"` писать проще, чем `"echo MyLib::MyFunc();"`

Comment: ну мне не проще, я с ООП дружу :)<br>
всеравно спасибо, подозреваю что спрашивать такое на собеседовании на вакансию middle программиста бред...<br>
Кароче еще одна ненужность типа <b>goto</b> походу...

Comment: притом это наворот php5.3. Видимо, суть вопроса была в проверке, следит ли человек за обновлениями языка. По крайней мере, тогда он хоть как-то логичен) Ой вей, а я не знал, что в php есть goto O_O День открытий прям. Это, кстати, хорошо \*коварный взгляд\*, можно обходить `get_defined_functions` `^___^`

Comment: Ну, например, я биологию в школе учил (причем на отлично), но сейчас ничего кроме общих каких-то определений не расскажу... А все потому, что не пригодилось, так и тут, если бы я в мане сегодня не наткнулся, не факт что вообще когда-то вспомнил бы об этом (и, подозреваю, жил бы и не тужил :))<br>
Про `get_defined_functions` это сурово ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, польза от namespaces просто огромная, т.к. позволяет ограничить область видимости классов/функций/etc, исключить конфликты имен и не заботится об их уникальности (пример класса из zend framework: `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_AutoComplete_Abstract`, к таким названиям классов приводит отсутствие namespaces).

В реалиях PHP-же, namespaces не только практически бесполезны, но и несовместимы с большинством современных фреймворков. Для того, что бы они были эффективны, нужно переписать *все* встроенные функции php и, соответственно, всю существующую кодовую базу PHP.

Хороший пример использования namespaces в PHP: [Zend Framework 2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2)

Хотя, наверное, лучший способ понять для чего нужны namespaces - это изучить какой-либо другой язык, который изначально проектировался с использованием namespaces. Например C#, Java или Python. Хотя в последнем пространства имен, по сути заменяет понятие модульности.

Comment: Зачем namespace в C++ и пакеты в java я прекрасно понимаю...<br>
Про фреймворки меня не напугало т.к. зачастую пишу без них :)
<br>
Меня интересовала имено реальная польза, пока из приведенных примеров толку я не вижу практически никакого..<br>
По поводу бесполезности - я так и думаю, но мало ли :)

Comment: > Зачем namespace в C++ и пакеты в java я прекрасно понимаю...

Тогда не понятно в чем вопрос. В PHP это абсолютно те-же самые немспейсы. С одним-лишь исключением: они нигде не используются (ни в core, ни в pecl-расширениях, ни в фреймвоорках), а потому не представляют сколько-либо значимой ценности.

Вот если бы разработчики PHP взяли и к 6'ой версии переписали бы все core и pecl функции с учетом namespaces...

Comment: А что непонятного то? Есть такая плюшка, что это я знаю, но толку в этом не видел, вспомнил о ней и решил убедится прав ли я.<br>
Заметьте вопрос не что это такое, а какой от них толк...<br>
Хотя я и согласен в том что они скорее всего бессполезны, но расширения и фреймворки не являются неотразимым аргументом...<br><br>
<small>PS:Angry Bird ну тема же была не о пространствах имен вообще а о пространствах имен в php, зачем было переименовывать то?</small>

Comment: Вообщем сделаем вывод что толку нет :)